# Ubuntu 14.04 : wrong keyboard input

Tags: keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, and when I try typing <kbd>f</kbd>, it is typed as <kbd>fb</kbd>. The same happens with <kbd>b</kbd>.

Also <kbd>j</kbd> appears as <kbd>jn</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd> as <kbd>jn</kbd> and many more keyboard inputs are erroneous.

Comment: check your keyboard layout: `setxkbmap -query`

Comment: @Arun this is what i get rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     in,us
variant:    eng,

Comment: Have you tried using different physical keyboards, or different keyboard layouts?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI it works fine with an external keyboard

Comment: Do other keyboard layouts have the same issue with the built-in keyboard, but not the external keyboard? If so, it's most likely a problem with the built-in keyboard.

Comment: built-in keyboard works fine under windows (i've my laptop dual booted)